# Accessing multiple firebase databases in one project

Tags: node.js, firebase

I'm looking for a way to create one central application that has data stored in multiple firebase projects. Is the only way to do this creating an API?

Comment: Why would you want to access data from different projects? If all the projects are your same app, you should be having it in just one project.

Comment: @s_o_m_m_y_e_e there are some cases when your only solution is to use different projects. For example, I had to use 2 projects because Firebase limit you to 200 compound indexes per projects and I need to use about 300

Comment: hmm, didn't think about that!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by calling `initializeApp` once for each project/database that you want to access. The full process is described in the documentation on [using multiple projects in your application](https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/multiprojects#use_multiple_projects_in_your_application).